# How to get back the default Xcode appearance

Tags: xcode4.2

I know it's unusual to ask such a question, but i gonna loose my temper, actually, the windows in Xcode has changed and i couldn't recover the default appearance.
[image] 
Can you tell me how could i do that? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have version editor switched on :)
In the top right, you have 2 groups of 2 buttons and 1 separate button. In the first group of 3 you have most right toggled on. Toggle most left ;)

-- edit --
And if you want Navigator or Debug area, toggle other 2 buttons in the 2nd group of 3.